# Apache2 doesn't execute .rb files (mod_ruby)

Tags: ruby, apache2

I want to make apache2 run ruby scripts. I managed to do this by using CGI, but now I want to go one step further and do it with mod_ruby. I installed mod_ruby through apt-get so it's supposed to be enabled, but when I visit http://localhost/test.rb my browser downloads the file instead of displaying it's output.

If I open /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ruby.load there is a line containing the path do this mod.

I also added the following lined to my apache2.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ruby.c>
  <Directory /var/www/>
    Options +ExecCGI
  </Directory>
  RubyRequire apache/ruby-run
  #RubySafeLevel 0
  <Files *.rb>
    SetHandler ruby-object
    RubyHandler Apache::RubyRun.instance
  </Files>
  <Files *.rbx>
    SetHandler ruby-object
    RubyHandler Apache::RubyRun.instance
  </Files>
</IfModule>
```

Can you please help me?

PS. Please don't suggest using ROR. I'm familiar with that. Now I just want to use ruby for educational reasons. Also please keep things simple I'm a total newbie to apache.

Comment: You are mentioning that mod_ruby _should_ be loaded, but I guess it doesn't hurt to check if there is a link in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ruby.load` that points to appropriate script in `mods-available`

Comment: Both ruby.load files (in mods-enabled and mods-available) have the same line pointing to mod_ruby.so. - I checked it exists in the directory they point to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this article](http://www.howtoforge.com/apache2-mod_ruby-with-ispconfig-2.2.20-and-above) - it has some instructions. Basically you need to tell Apache to pass your Ruby files through the handler.

Also, consider trying [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) - it's a micro web framework that's as simple as plain ruby files. And it runs with [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) which is the *well-documented* Ruby module for Apache.

Comment: I'm using debian so according to the article you mentioned just installing mod_ruby through apt-get should be enough. I also tried adding the lines mentioned in that article to apache2.conf

Answer (score 2):

The article on HowtoForge covers almost the whole story, but I needed to add one line inside the `<Directory /var/www>` directive to prevent browsers from downloading the file:

```
AddType text/html .rb .rbx
```

Here are a couple more sites that I found helpful:

- https://defuse.ca/blog/2012/07/how-to-install-mod_ruby-on-debian-squeeze/
- http://modruby.net/en/doc/

Answer (score 1):

Debian Stretch 9.

I tried installing `mod_ruby` with `apt-get install libapache2-mod-ruby` but there is no package by that name. In the end, all I needed to do was add this line to the apache-config to get the server to run my scripts.

```
    AddHandler cgi-script .rb
```

Comment: Okay, now I realize, that OP already was this far and this does not really answer OP's question. However I came here via google and others will, too. Also, hearing that `libapache2-mod-ruby` has apparently turned into a non-thing might be interesting to see.